# How to access the layer of a view?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I would like to apply a transformation (rotation) to a `UIImageView`. I could just set the `transform` property of the view, but wouldn't setting the layer's `transform` make it faster? If so, how can I achieve this?

Assuming I have a `UIImageView` initialized with an image, can anyone help? Wouldn't it be better to have a `UIVIew` with a `UIImageView` in it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing a simple rotation, the speed difference is probably insignificant, but you can get access to a view's layer by doing:

`view.layer`

So, you can just use

`view.layer.affineTransform = newTranform;`

Comment: what do you mean by speed difference? it is never constant even if you specify the animation to be linear?

Comment: you asked if setting the layer's transform would make it faster; that's the speed difference I was referring to.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a constant rotation using a CAAnimation that auto repeats (I think; I haven't actually tried to do this exact thing, but similar stuff).

If one animation won't do it, certainly two will (have one rotate 180°, then when it ends, have another one fire to do the second 180°. This can be done on either the view or its layer. You'll definitely want to test this on a device for performance.

No need to use NSTimer; this is what CoreAnimation is built for.